# Django throws 500 when debug is False in Production

Tags: django, django-urls, django-i18n

I am unable to understand why Django 3 fails when I run with `DEBUG=False`. Also there seems to be a problem with urls:

```
www.domain.com/ -> Does not work
www.domain.com/en/ -> No problem
```

The logs seem to mention a million problems but I don't understand what the initial problem is, so I am looking for help:

```
Exception while resolving variable 'self' in template '404.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 167, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
  File "/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 290, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 585, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) '^django-admin/'>], [<URLResolver <module 'wagtail.admin.urls' from '/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py'> (None:None) '^admin/'>], [<URLResolver <module 'wagtail.documents.urls' from '/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/documents/urls.py'> (None:None) '^documents/'>], [<URLPattern '^i18n/$' [name='set_language']>], [<URLPattern '^sitemap\.xml$'>], [<URLResolver <URLResolver list> (None:None) 'bg/'>]], 'path': ''}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
  File "/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'self'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 835, in _resolve_lookup
    if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(type(current), bit):
AttributeError: type object 'RequestContext' has no attribute 'self'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'self'

#####################
# ...
# Rest of debug lines: https://pastebin.com/5AqDZu11
# ...
#####################

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'url_name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'url_name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pp/www/SmileDesign/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [url_name] in None
Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 680
```

I see that it says `Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico` at the bottom, and I am suspecting this to be the culprit, but the problem persists even if I try a workaround such as:

```
    url(r'^favicon.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('img/favicon.ico'), permanent=True)),
```

I still get 500 ending in:

```
Internal Server Error: /
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 680
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 301 0
"GET /static/img/favicon.be884a05bb00.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 9896
```

By looking at the very first line, it seems to be an issue with the `404.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body_class %}template-404{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Page not found</h1>

    <h2>Sorry, this page could not be found.</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

If I remove the line for extending base.html, it all runs, But I am not clear why.

```
{% load static wagtailuserbar %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/is-mobile.min.js' %}"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>
            {% block title %}
                {% if self.seo_title %}
                    {{ self.seo_title }}
                {% elif self.translated_title %}
                    {{ self.translated_title }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ self.title }}
                {% endif %}
            {% endblock %}
            {% block title_suffix %}
                {% with self.get_site.site_name as site_name %}
                    {% if site_name %}- {{ site_name }}{% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
            {% endblock %}
        </title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon.ico' %}">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <meta name="description" content="{% block meta_description %}{% endblock %}" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="{% block meta_keywords %}{% endblock %}" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'slick/slick.css' %}"/>

        {# Global stylesheets #}
        {% if debug %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
        {% else %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.min.css' %}">
        {% endif %}

        {% if not request.is_preview %}
            {# The page is not in preview mode #}
            {# Put google analytics, mixpanel, etc... here #}
        {% endif %}

        {% block extra_css %}
            {# Override this in templates to add extra stylesheets #}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
        {% wagtailuserbar %}
        {% block navigation %}
        {% include 'partials/_navigation.html' %}
        {% endblock %}

        <div class="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>

        {% block footer %}
        {% include 'partials/_footer.html' %}
        {% endblock %}

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'slick/slick.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@3.3.5/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/parallax.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>

        <script id="developedby" data-client-id="d640d636-cbe0-493c-b51a-124becd2cd6d" src="https://hakomo.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/static/js/webdevelopmentbyhakomo.js"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/min/main.js' %}"></script>
        {% block extra_js %}
            {# Override this in templates to add extra javascript #}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    url(r'^i18n/$', set_language, name='set_language'),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, sitemaps),
    url(r'^favicon.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('img/favicon.ico'), permanent=True)),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    # These URLs will have /<language_code>/ appended to the beginning

    url(r'', include(content_urls)),

    url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),

 
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),

)


if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    # Serve static and media files from development server
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

1. So besides understanding why extending base is an issue,
2. I am also wondering why at all we are getting 404 to begin with.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The Problem is related to Template Variables. Can you show your view which renders `base.html`

Answer (score 0):

The First Line Says :

```
Exception while resolving variable 'self' in template '404.html'.
```

And You have used `self` in your `base.html`, therefore when you remove

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

It all works.

So Django is unable to resolve the variable `self`,

Please update your Question with `views.py` which passes this context variable `self` to `base.html`

That will clear out things for sure

Also we should avoid using reserved keywords like `self` as variable name in Python